# System.NullPointerException Error for new method to be deployed through Change Set

Tags: deployment, null-pointer

I have added a new method in a class and added test data in the test class .
It was PASS when I Ran the test class in Sandbox.

However , when I'm trying to deploy in Prod through Change Set, It's giving me "Null pointer Exception " error .

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
>       Stack Trace: Class.MyClass.MyNewMethod: line 516, column 1 
>       Class.MyClassTest.MyTestMethod: line 73, column 1

MyNewMethod is the same method which I have written newly and trying to deploy.

Please suggest why such error.

Comment: If you don't share any code it will be hard for us to know why the code threw a null pointer exception

Comment: Please share your code.
You need to put null checks through out the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that you have a hard-coded ID in your test from the sandbox that will be different or non-existent in production.

You will need to remove all hard-coded IDs from the tests and make them org independant by setting up the required test data within the test.